# SQL Server: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_T' on table 'T' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server

I get the error message in SQL Server 2008 (when introducing a new FK):

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_T' on table 'T' may cause cycles
>   or multiple cascade paths

I understand the theory that I can't come to the same table from multiple paths. My problem is that my database structure is rather complex with a lot of FKs already setup on this table to other tables and from other tables. Is there some query that I can run to tell me where the problem is?

Best I could think of so far was to

```
for each FK on my table:
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  DROP FK
  ADD MY NEW FK  
  --see if it breaks
ROLLBACK
```

Then analyze FK on table which broke the "ADD NEW FK" in the same manner. There must be a better way...

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  There are some system views and stored procs you can use to  view dependencies that may assist.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 (I just added it to the description also)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server management studio you can right click any object and select show dependencies. This will show you what depends on that object and what that object depends on.

//edit
SSMS uses SMO so I'm not sure if this can be done with pure SQL, but probably it is possible.